# In GCD, when do I use a global concurrent queue vs a custom concurrent queue?

Tags: ios, macos, grand-central-dispatch

In GCD, there are two ways I can run blocks concurrently.

I can use one of the global pools:

```
DispatchQueue.global().async() {
  // do work
}
```

or I can create my own queue:

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "process images", attributes: [.concurrent])
queue.async {
  // do work
}
```

but I can't find much information on when to prefer one over the other.

Some places (including [this](https://gist.github.com/tclementdev/6af616354912b0347cdf6db159c37057) summary of mailing list posts from the libdispatch maintainer) suggest that you really shouldn't use the global queues.

Yet most code examples just dispatch to a global queue, and there are even some sources that say you really shouldn't use *custom* queues - and should prefer the *global* queues.

Which situations are better for each kind of queue? Somewhat relatedly, some articles advise preferring serial queues over concurrent queues - but obviously they have completely different parallelism characteristics, so it's odd to see them suggested as interchangeable.

Comment: see this topic is arguable, but the thing is that if you have less task to execute then you can use global queue, system also use global queue. The situation when you probably use your own custom queues is if you are designing a framework or a manager class, where you might be handling much more queuing of task.

Comment: This is a fantastic question fyi as I've been researching this exact confusion for a few days.

Comment: @johnbakers Did you ever arrive at a conclusion here? Apple's own wording in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue makes no sense given that a private concurrent queue just targets a global queue.

Comment: https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit/discussions/1197 seems to back me up on this, that the issue isn't the _creation_ of private concurrent queues but the # of things scheduled for parallel execution. Which is obvious.... well at least 1 reason to avoid private concurrent queues is that they used to have bugs: https://gist.github.com/steipete/aa71bfd6fbd02de9e95ae2a92313e08e

Answer (score 7):

In addition to concerns about efficiency and thread explosion, with your own concurrent queue, you can:

- Specify a label that's meaningful to you for debugging
- Suspend it
- Set and get app-specific data
- Submit barrier tasks

None of these are possible with the global concurrent queues.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Are there any downsides to always using custom current queues?

Comment: I'm not aware of any.

Comment: Well, Apple says we should avoid using custom concurrent queues, if they are not necessary: [Avoiding Excessive Thread Creation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue)

Comment: @Sascha That text is a bit confusing. It says "creating additional concurrent dispatch queues exacerbates the thread consumption problem" but the target of a concurrent queue is exactly the global queue. So I don't see how # of threads spawned would ever be different. In both case you are limited to GCD limit of 64.  What I think it probably means is that because the differences between private concurrent & global concurrent are negligible, the latter should be favored due to possibly lower overhead and more importantly reduced complexity in code